# Jquery setdate sets date less than one than the actual selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using jquery datepicker for date field.
HTML :

```
<input class="timepicker" name="timepicker" id="from-datepicker"/>
```

Now, I am setting date as :

```
var dateToSet = 2016-05-20;
$('#from-datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date(dateToSet));
```

However, the value that is set is 2016-05-19 instead of 20th .

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think,it's an issue due to  your timezone . 
While setting date,  you have to add your timezone offset.

Let's say, your timezone is  UTC-05:00

```
var actual_date =   new Date(new Date(url_from_date).getTime() + 5 * 3600 * 1000 );
$('#from-datepicker').datepicker("setDate", actual_date );
```

Other way to do this by first getting value from datepicker and then adding offset.

```
 var date = $('#from-datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
 date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
```

Comment: I had success hard-coding the timezone, too, if that's of any use. `var date = new Date('2016-05-20 EST');` using that as the date in datepicker's `setDate` option, it shows 5/20 instead of 5/19 (I'm in EST).

Comment: Did you try that as I suggested.. I tried your date snippet in console , it does not add timezone, I'm still getting mine even addeing `EST` in date string

Comment: I didn't try what you suggested - but then I didn't ask the question, so it doesn't really matter. I was just contributing to your answer. Here's an example of it working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/h2Ljpkmb/, again, I am in EST, so it may differ depending on where you are.

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz Thanks man ! :) 
It worked. I'm in PST 
 var from_timezone =   new Date(new Date(url_from_date).getTime() + 7 * 3600 * 1000 );
        $('#from-datepicker').datepicker("setDate", from_timezone );

Comment: @nerd.post What about second solution? Did that work.. or you did not try because first one worked :)